# Gradle: Any way to output build results in a computer readable format, such as XML?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using gradle (and specifically gradlew) to automatically built some Android apps, and would like to capture the output of this task and process it automatically. The output from a gradle build is nice for humans to read, but isn't easily parsed by a program.

Is there any way to get gradle to output build results in a computer readable format such as XML or JSON?

Even a simple text format with one build error per line would be better than the default output.

Comment: Output of which tasks you are looking in particular? What info do you need exactly?

Comment: @Opal The build task, and i want to know what the specific errors are.